# how to convert transferring file through ftp to GIt

Tags: php, git

I want to use GIT in my project. Right now, i download file from FTP server and then upload it after updating the code. I want to use GIT where i download entire code from server and then through commit and push it goes to server. I don't want use some git application that support FTP but actual GIT. How i can achieve this. Thanks.

Comment: Do a git clone on the server, then git pull when there's an update? Not a deployment route I'd recommend though.

Comment: git is not initialized on server yet. So i assume, i need to setup locally and then on server. But i am struggling to know exact commands to run locally and then on server.

Comment: How to install and use git is well documented online already. Do you have a specific issue you're struggling with?

Answer (score 0):

Due to you already having an existing code base i will be telling you how to add to a repository.

To use git you will need a repository service like Github or Gitlab. Make sure you have an account and create a repository for your project.

Once you have git installed open a command line in the folder

```
Git init
```

This will initialize the folder for git, you may have notice a .git file appear in your ide. This hidden folder is the configuration. Depending on the operating system the instructions may be different.

Open a command line terminal in your directory and enter

```
git config --global user.name “Your Git Repository Username”

git config --global user.email “Your Git Repository Email Address”
```

Next you will do

```
Git add .
```

This will tell git to prepare all of the files in the existing folder.

Git remote add origin “Your git Repository link ending in a .git” 
This will tell git to where it is going to upload (push) the files to, i have told it in this command to call the branch(branches are a version you can work in, you could have a beta version, stable etc) origin.

```
Git commit -m “These are notes for the repository”
```

This will add notes to the push, normally comment on what has been changed.

```
Git push
```

**You will be asked to login to GIT to verify the git installation.**

This will push/upload the contents of the folder, **make sure you have nothing that is personal in this code because unless you have set the repo to private then it will be public by default on most platforms.** It will never push the .git folder.

Ok so when you want to download from a repo its best to again setup git via the Git init & git remote add commands

Then you are able to

```
Git pull origin master
```

I hope this helped, any questions i will be around to answer them.

Comment: Actually i want to do it without involving Github.This is what i want. I have folder on my local machine say MyProject and a folder on my remote server MyProjectRemote. Initializing git locally and on remote server and then adding remote origin with command like git remote add origin on my local machine so that when i run following command on my local machine then it should push the code to remote server:

git add .
git commit -am "first push"
git push origin master

I am trying to work on these lines but unable to push and see pushed files on my remote server.